# How to "rip out" an ftp connection from total commander or open it through a c# application?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, nuget

Hello i need to display ftp connection window from total commander in c# application.

All I found was the discovery of the total commander itself, but I still didn’t understand how to further interact with it through applications (I think it’s impossible, but still). thanks for answers

Comment: Open a cmd.exe and type >Help cmd.  You need to use the /K option to keep windows open.

Comment: You can't embed a foreign process in your application. And in order to interact with you would have to check if the TotalCommander exposes an API. It doesn't. You could write a custom plugin that exposes the data you need or check if there is some plugin you find useful. Not sure what "'rip out' an FTP connection" means. Maybe you receive more valuable help if you would explain what your goals are.